# ASPx ReadOnly field not working with inner code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple

```
<dx:CardViewTextColumn FieldName="Role" ReadOnly="<% isAdmin() %>" />
```

I tried isAdmin() to return a bool or a string but I am not able to make it work...

Comment: What is `IsAdmin()` and where does it come from? Also, could you elaborate that what is not working?

Comment: Use a DataBinding expression: `ReadOnly='<%# isAdmin() %>'`. And call `DataBind()` if the element is not in a GridView, Repeater etc.